# Replace table in html file with text....(e.g. @@##There was a table here)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am extracting text from an html file in python using beautifulsoup. I want to extract all text data and discard tables. But can we do something to replace the table in the html with a text ( e.g. " @@## There was a table here @@## ")

I was able to read the html file using beautifulsoup and removed table uisng strip_tables(html). But not sure how remove table and replace with text specifying a table was here.

```
def strip_tables(soup):
    """Removes all tables from the soup object."""
    for script in soup(["table"]): 
        script.extract()
    return soup

sample_html_file = "/Path/file.html"
html = read_from_file(sample_html_file) 
# This function reads the file and returns a file handle for beautifulsoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
my_text = strip_tables( soup ).text
```

This is html file with table:

```
By order of the Board of Directors, /s/ JOSHUA H. LEVINE Joshua H. Levine  President and Chief Executive OfficerSunnyvale, California  October 4, 2018

Table of Contents  TABLE OF CONTENTS             Page   QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS REGARDING  THIS SOLICITATION AND VOTING AT THE ANNUAL MEETING      1   PROPOSAL ONEELECTION OF  DIRECTORS      7   Classes of our Board      7   Director NomineesClass III Directors      7   Continuing DirectorsClass I and Class II Directors      8   Board of Directors Recommendation      11   PROPOSAL TWOTO APPROVE  AN AMENDMENT TO OUR 2016 EQUITY INCENTIVE PLAN TO INCREASE THE NUMBER OF SHARES OF COMMON STOCK AUTHORIZED FOR ISSUANCE UNDER SUCH PLAN      12   Summary of the Amended 2016 Plan      13   Summary of U.S. Federal Income Tax Consequences      20   New Plan Benefits      22   Existing Plan Benefits to Employees and Directors      23   Board of Directors Recommendation      23   PROPOSAL THREETO APPROVE  AN AMENDMENT TO OUR 2007 EMPLOYEE STOCK PURCHASE PLAN TO INCREASE THE NUMBER OF SHARES OF COMMON STOCK AUTHORIZED FOR ISSUANCE UNDER SUCH PLAN        A-1   APPENDIX B     AMENDED AND RESTATED 2007 EMPLOYEE STOCK PURCHASE PLAN      B-1    ii    Table of Contents    PROXY STATEMENT FOR  ACCURAY INCORPORATED  2018 ANNUAL MEETING OF STOCKHOLDERS  TO BE HELD ON NOVEMBER 16, 2018      

This proxy statement (Proxy Statement) is furnished to our stockholders of record as of the close of business on September 20, 2018 (the Record Date)
```

This is data after strip_tables:

```
By order of the Board of Directors, /s/ JOSHUA H. LEVINE Joshua H. Levine  President and Chief Executive OfficerSunnyvale, California  October 4, 2018
     This proxy statement (Proxy Statement) is furnished to our stockholders of record as of the close of business on September 20, 2018 (the Record Date)
```

*Expected outcome*

```
By order of the Board of Directors, /s/ JOSHUA H. LEVINE Joshua H. Levine  President and Chief Executive OfficerSunnyvale, California  October 4, 2018 
" @@## There was a table here @@## "
This proxy statement (Proxy Statement) is furnished to our stockholders of record as of the close of business on September 20, 2018 (the Record Date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to use `replaceWith()` instead `extract()` in strip_tables function. Hope it help you.

```
def strip_tables(soup):
    """Removes all tables from the soup object."""
    for script in soup(["table"]): 
        script.replaceWith(" @@## There was a table here @@## ")
```

Comment: is `return soup` needed?

Comment: Sorry about that. It is not needed. Thank you.